# Cakephp 2.1 Router::connect /* except some actions

Tags: regex, cakephp

I would like to know whether it's possible to have something like this next line but with the exclusion of some actions. Because I would like to have manage, add, delete,... to go to the respective action and not to the display action. I know it's possible by specifying these rules explicitely upfront, but if you have quite some of these it will not look to good in the router file.

```
 Router::connect('/paginas/manage', array('controller' => 'paginas', 'action' => 'manage')); 
 ...
 Router::connect('/paginas/*', array('controller' => 'paginas', 'action' => 'display'));
```

So the aim is to remove the first line...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this in your PaginasController which is basicly the PagesController I think.:
....

```
public function display(){
// Assuming default behavior of cakephp here
...
if (!empty($path[0])) {
    $page = $path[0];
    if(
        method_exists($this, $page) &&
        !in_array(
            $page,
            array(
                // Methods that never should be executed in this controller are going in here
            )
        )
    ){
        $this->{$page}();
    }
}
}
```

This would execute a specific method in the controller. You could exit it there to make it stop working afterwards.
This might be a bit dangerous though because it can access parent methods of AppController, too.

The other way in which you also need exactly two of those Router::connect() rules one described here: http://api.cakephp.org/class/router#method-Routerconnect

```
Router::connect(
  'paginas/:action/*',
  array(),
  array('paginas' => '(manage|add|delete)')
);
```

This one goes first followed by the other one. **Never tested!**

Though I don't see why there should be public methods for editing pages. Use these to seperate them from the rest: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

I recommend, if you are trying to do this what I am thinking of, that you won't start to write a management for pages using the PagesController. "Pages" is a more or less reserved word in cake and you can get in big trouble with using those words (wrote a "File" plugin once including a "File" model. Waste of time as if since cake1.2 or 1.3 there is actually a "File" class to handle file operations). Create something new like "ContentPage" or whatever for it. You are on a saver side then. This paragraph is maybe useless, because your controller is not even named "Pages", but I hate to delete long ones, so it stays, just in case you need this information once.

Also i recommend not to change programming language, which means, you either use english or spanish or whatever but not both or worst more. You could name your route whatever you want to, but the class names should maybe stay in english because cake is also.

Greetings
func0der

Comment: Pages Controller doesn't has any logic in other actions than the display action. But something like the first code example could indeed solve the problem. And is the most likely solution for my problem.

But the proposal of prefix-routing might be even better for me, as the methods I want to make accessible should not be public anyway.

Comment: Glad I could help you out ;)